# Is there a way to make PC running Windows 7 forward packets via the same interface on which they arrived?

Tags: windows-7, windows, routing, gateway

I'm testing a NEWT configuration to be used for an Internet simulation between 16 peers. The NEWT host will be running on a dedicated PC as opposed to one of the peers, and all peers and the NEWT host will be physically connected to the same network. The PC that I'm using as a NEWT host to test the configuration is running Windows 7, and this will most likely be the version of Windows used for the Internet simulation.

The route command is sufficient to make the peers attempt to use the NEWT host as a gateway; with the appropriate routes configured on the peers, NEWT's RT packet monitor shows packets sent from one peer to another peer arriving at the NEWT host.

But the route command isn't sufficient to make the NEWT host actually be a gateway; packets sent from one peer to another do not reach their destinations when the peers try to use the NEWT host as a gateway.

The fact that the NEWT host would have to forward the packets via the same interface on which they arrived may be part of the problem, but I would prefer to avoid using multiple interfaces on the NEWT host.

So is there a way to make a PC running Windows 7 forward packets on the same interface on which they arrived?

Comment: Minor thing, but what is NEWT?

Comment: Network Emulator for Windows Toolkit.